# How to add subscripts in the row names of a renderTable (Shiny)?

Tags: r, shiny

How to add subscripts in the row names of a `renderTable`? In the following example I need subscripts in `A_1` and `A_2`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(tableOutput("table"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({data <- data.frame(c(1, 2),
                                         row.names = c("A_1", "A_2"))}, rownames = T)}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DT` package for datatable for that. You need to use html tags with `escape = FALSE`. Have a look at the modified your code below:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)
  ui <- fluidPage(dataTableOutput("table"))

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      data <- datatable(data.frame(c(1, 2), row.names = c("A<sub>1</sub>", "A<sub>2</sub>")), rownames = T, escape = FALSE)
      })
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You get a table which looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can add subscript for `renderTable` by using html tags with `sanitize.text.function = function(x) x`. The code would be as shown below:

```
 library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(tableOutput("table"))

    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$table <- renderTable({data <- data.frame(c(1, 2),
                                                      row.names = c("A<sub>1</sub>", "A<sub>1</sub>"))}, rownames = T, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)}

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output table will look as follows:
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: The layout of `datatable` does not suit my purpose. I am looking for a solution with `rendertable`.

Comment: @Joe I have edited my answer  with solution for `renderTable`. Hope it helps!