# R format text in table

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

It seems like a simple question. But I have not found an answer yet for formatting text in a table (superscript, subscript, underline, etc). For example, if I want to format text "ABCDEFG" and "HIJK" to the following format and render in a table.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714367/how-to-add-subscripts-in-the-row-names-of-a-rendertable-shiny

Comment: Very helpful information. I used `rhandsontable` instead `DT` table, but probably is helpful for me to explore more. Thx.

Comment: Update! The link by `akrun` provides some hints. The answer is to use htmal tags and then renderhtml in table cells.